# Newbie question about updates vs upgrades/installations

Tags: system-installation, updates

I just installed elementary 0.4. It was super-easy to do, congrats to the team.
Now the app-center shows that I've got 1GB worth of updates to download just for the os alone. That seems a bit scary to me, and my internet access is not unlimited either.

Question: Will I have any problem if I just wait until elementary 0.5 is released, and then upgrade (if possible) or re-install? (preferably without losing my documents).

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid to tell you that in any modern OS (not matter if we talk about MS Windows, Mac OS...)  you should always upgrade as it is necessary for security reasons.  You should work without updates only in a closed system with no connection to internet or any other net (it means using your system for document editing, playing music and things like that). So, if you require connection to internet you must update your system to prevent security issues. The god news is that once you had done this first update the size of updates is small compared to other operating systems.

**Updated: May 25th 2017:**

There has been a major update to elementary OS Loki: version 0.4.1. On May 17th so if you can get the ISO you won't have to download many files to have your system updated.

For more information: 
https://medium.com/elementaryos/new-release-elementary-os-loki-0-4-1-2a756549ee76

Answer (score 0):

But if you re-download the new version of 0.5 it will probably take even bigger amount of traffic...
I don't think theres a way around it

Comment: I referred to get a copy from another user or buy a copy in dvd (which is only $ 5.95) https://www.osdisc.com/products/elementary Dont forget to make a donation afterwards. ;-)